# Unable to make DateTime.Parse work properly

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I'm learning how to use MVC4 and Entity Framework, and to do that I'm following the Contoso University tutorials. In chapter 4, I'm asked to generate a Seed for my DB, but when I try to update it the PMC shows me there's an error.

This is one of the entities:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;    

namespace ContosoUniversityMVC4.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3,  ErrorMessage ="Some error message")]
        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]    
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is the code part of the seed in which I pass values for this entity:

```
var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Carson", LastName = "Alexander", EnrollmentDate  = DateTime.Parse("2010­-09­-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Meredith", LastName = "Alonso", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-­09-­01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Arturo", LastName = "Anand", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013­-09­-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Gytis", LastName = "Barzdukas", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-­09-­01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Yan", LastName = "Li", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012­-09­-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Peggy", LastName = "Justice", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2011­-09-­01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Laura", LastName = "Norman", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013­-09­-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Nino", LastName = "Olivetto", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2005­-09-­01") }
            };

            students.ForEach(s => context.Students.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();
```

And this is the error the PMC shows:

```
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying code-based migrations: [201402051617351_Chap4C].
Applying code-based migration: 201402051617351_Chap4C.
Running Seed method.
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)
   at ContosoUniversityMVC4.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(SchoolContext context) in c:\Users\f9243821\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ContosoUniversityMVC4\ContosoUniversityMVC4\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 20
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

It's clearly visible that it can't convert the date I'm trying to pass into a valid DB datetime format. I've checked the DB and the field type is "datetime" (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.nnn as I could see when hand editing) as well. "Line 20" refers to "var students = new List", which led me to think that I couldn't pass the "student" section of the seed correctly.

I've tried to change the value of the string (for instance, yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss), or to delete de ".Parse" property and try to pass a date directly, but so far I couldn't solve the problem.

This code was wrote following the guidelines of the tutorial since I don't fully understand what I'm doing (since this is new to me and I'm trying to learn).

Could you please tell me what I've done wrong? If you need more information about this (VS/SQL versions, more code, etc.) please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure but could you try removing [DataType(DataType.Date)]

Comment: Field type is database?  What does that mean?

Comment: No, just remove that line from Enrollmentdate. My guess is that parsing the date like you are doing is also including the hour which you don't need (since you typed enrollmentdate as a Date, not a DateTime)

Comment: @DanBracuk LOL, my mistake. The field in the DB is "datetime".

Comment: @S4NDERR, I tried to update de DB commenting that line but the same error shows.

Comment: Okay, my guess was totally wrong. James's answer is the correct one.

Comment: Why don't you just set `DateTime` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with EF Migrations, EF or SQL, this is to do with the fact that the date you are trying to parse is not in the correct format for your culture your app is running under. [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will use the current system culture date format to attempt to parse your date string, if it doesn't match it throws a `FormatException`.

When manually parsing dates it's best to use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you to specify the exact format of date you are trying to parse e.g.

```
EnrollmentDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-09-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot James. I first tried with your suggestion using "null" as the third parameter with no luck; now I tried the CultureInfo variant and I'm getting the following error: "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.". I'm investigating this to know which is the error. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: @Rambo3 yeah passing `null` was actually the same problem as before (because it defaults to the current culture, that was my bad). However, the `EntityValidationErrors` will be a completely separate issue.